# Bold symbols in LuaLaTeX with setmathfont

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, bm

How to type bold `\wedge` and `\neg` symbols in a selected math font?

MWE1, with `bm` package, no math font selection:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[%
Numbers =   {OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures =   TeX, 
]
%\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} 
\begin{document}
Hello, 1, 2, 3; $1,2,3$

$\bm{p\wedge q}\quad p\wedge q\quad \delta,\bm{\delta}\quad a + b\quad \bm{a + b}$ 

$\bm{\neg p}\quad\neg p\quad  \lambda \bm{\lambda}$ 

\end{document}
```

[image: Output MWE1]

MWE2, with `unicode-math` and `setmathfont`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[%
Numbers   =   {OldStyle, Proportional},
Ligatures =   TeX,
]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Hello, 1, 2, 3; $1,2,3$

$\symbf{p\wedge q}\quad p\wedge q\quad
\delta, \symbf{\delta}\quad a + b\quad \symbf{a + b}$

$\symbf{\neg p}\quad\neg p\quad  \lambda \symbf{\lambda}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output MWE2]

How to get bold `\wedge` and `\neg` in MWE2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those symbols are in fact available from the text font, which is already loaded in bold, so if it is just one or two symbols needed it's probably simpler to access the text font, and then use `\mathbin` to set the right math spacing. I did it inline here but you could define a local `\boldwedge` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[%
Numbers =   {OldStyle, Proportional}, Ligatures =   TeX, 
]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} 
\begin{document}
Hello, 1, 2, 3; $1,2,3$

$ p \wedge q \longrightarrow 
     \symbfit{p} \mathbin{\text{\normalfont\bfseries \wedge}} \symbfit{q} $ 



\end{document}
```